# Express.js storing the rawBody with middleware.

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use middleware in express.js to get the rawBody of a request. It seems that its not reading the data chunks in the use command. Is this because the data variable doesn't exist??? I also tried placing this command before the call webserver.use(bodyParser.json()); (since I also need the json).It doesn't work whether I place before or after...

```
webserver.use(function(req, res, next) {
        req.rawBody = '';

        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            logger.error('in here'); //doesn't go into data. 
            req.rawBody += chunk;
        });
        logger.error(req.rawBody); //raw.rawBody is completely empty
        next();
});




webserver.post('/slack/receive', function(req, res) {
      //gets inside here after
});
```

Comment: `req.on('data'` is asynchronous. The callback doesn't get invoked immediately, it gets invoked as data comes in. That's the whole reason there's a callback at all (otherwise it'd likely be `req.getData()` or somesuch). All event handlers (`.on`/`addListener`) behave this way. There should be an `'end'` or 'complete' event or something -- when that fires, *then* `req.rawBody` should be populated. You might want to defer calling `next()` until then.

Comment: when I add: req.on("end"){} it never goes inside of it :O

Comment: There should be an `end` event. Express extends from Node's built-in. They describe exactly what you're trying to do [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body).

Comment: Or just use [`bodyParser.raw`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)

Comment: unfortunately bodyParser.raw doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Then you have to back up and find where you bug is. Maybe remove some middlewares, or move this middleware up the chain. They give lots of examples on that page; try to get one of them working. Failing that, we'll need to see some more code -- post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you can.